# How to create a Python dictionary from the user inputted data in a specific format?

Tags: python, dictionary, input

What I want to do is first insert the key into the dictionary then after hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> insert the value. This is to be done for `n` number of key, value pairs.

```
n = 3
d = dict(input().split() for _ in range(n))
print (d)
```

Using this method I have to insert key and value at the same time, which I don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
output = {}
for _ in range(n):
   key = input("Enter Key:")
   value = input("Enter Value:")
   output[key] = value
return output
```

your pseudocode had it right.  You could try to code golf it to one line with multiple inputs but that will make it less readable.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that:

```
n = 3
d = {input('Key:'): input('Value:') for _ in range(n)}
print (d)
```

You were not that far!

Comment: fair - not that much less readable I guess

Comment: agreed, but I tried to stick to his code as much as possible

Comment: It's quite readable and succinct. But It first take "Value" instead of "Key" data :)

Comment: Your input command is starting from the value and then key.

Comment: Ok maybe it runs it that way, interesting, however the final duct is correct, that’s funny